# Spring form object. How to avoid empty objects in collection if I pass indexes with huge values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, collections, spring-form

I have following controller method:

```
public ResponseEntity putData(@ModelAttribute LocationInventoryRequestResponseWrapper requestResponseWrapper) {
```

On html I have following code:

```
<ul id="location-list">
       <li>
            <span>
                <label for="response.locations[9].code">code</label>
                <input name="response.locations[9].code" type="text">
            </span>
            <span>
                <label for="response.locations[9].userCode">userCode</label>
                <input name="response.locations[9].userCode" type="text">
            </span>
            <span>
                <label for="response.locations[9].primary">primary</label>
                <input name="response.locations[9].primary" type="text">
            </span>
            <input type="button" value="-" class="remove-location">
        </li>

        <li>
            <span>
                <label for="response.locations[10].code">code</label>
                <input name="response.locations[10].code" type="text">
            </span>
            <span>
                <label for="response.locations[10].userCode">userCode</label>
                <input name="response.locations[10].userCode" type="text">
            </span>
            <span>
                <label for="response.locations[10].primary">primary</label>
                <input name="response.locations[10].primary" type="text">
            </span>
            <input type="button" value="-" class="remove-location">
        </li>
    </ul>
```

inside `<form:form`

I have ui which can adds/remove html part and it leads that I have indexes like 9 and 10 without 1-8
When I accept this object in spring controller I have List with 11 elements.
0-8 - empty elements(null values inside)
9-10 - elements values from form.

On client side it is enough uncomfortable to recalculate indexes after any modifications.

Please advise pure spring way how to avoid these empty values on server side inside collection ?

Comment: Well... `myCollection.removeAll(null);`?

Comment: My suggestion would be to check if the object is not null before adding it to the list(if you are not doing it now).

Comment: @Kayaman 1. collection has high level non null object but any other level contains nul values. 2.Where should I invoke this method?

Comment: @NightsWatch It is spring job)

Comment: @gstackoverflow Well, anywhere before you start processing the elements. You could add the logic to your form object, so it's automatic.

Comment: @Kayaman I understood that I can do it in first line of controller method but for me this solution smell

Comment: Is your html form backed by a spring bean such as form model? if so then in ithe spring bean setter for the collection, you could perform the removeAll function.

Comment: @Chris Doyle setter for collections doesn't invoke. Possibly that spring gets collection and modify it through link